# Why does Stack Overflow Careers match "Java" to JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, jobs

Now, I know that it's probably as simple as pseudo code `if(job.contain("Java")) return true` But I still feel like Stack Overflow Careers should know better. True, a lot of Java devs know JavaScript, I do, but when I want to have a subscription for Java jobs, I don't expect to see JavaScript. It's something I'd expect from a recruiter mentioning "DNS" and "Git" as programming languages...

[image]

Also, if I try to use the `tag` system I've now understood exist *(feature request on it popping up tags as keywords?)* then I still get the same results:
[image]

[bug-fix](/questions/tagged/bug-fix) maybe?

Comment: I guess because you search for keyword 'Java' which include 'JavaScript', not tag `[java]`?

Comment: Not working, and so is `[tag:java]`... I will remove my answer.

Comment: After experimenting, I guess the issue is bigger than this... First, unlike on SE sites, it seems impossible to use `[tag]` as search keyword; it will be treated as normal keyword. The only way to search by tag is by clicking the tag itself, but... Second, search by tag itself is broken (or perhaps, *not effective*). In addition of returning jobs based on their tag, **it would include the result as if it's searched by keyword again**. (Observed on `[java]`, go to last page, there are many jobs that don't even have both `[java]`, **and** `[javascript]`.. if it's the original issue)